# Trouble with authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I´m facing a confusion issue while implementing the authentication for my restful api using passport local strategy.

Note: 
I got the authentication working successfully when I´m doing it all in my index.js. But I want to use in Classes for better Code separation.

I have a passport.js Module

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

module.exports = function(passport) {

// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        //console.log("SER");
        console.log(user),
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log("XXXX");
        console.log(user);
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? ",user.name, function(err, rows){
            console.log("DER");
            console.log(rows);
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });

// passport local strategy for local-login, local refers to this app
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(
        function (username, password, done) {
            console.log("hhh");
            console.log(username);
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? ",username, function(err, rows){
                console.log(rows);
                return done(err, rows[0]);
            });
        })
    );

    // route middleware to ensure user is logged in
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};
```

This is my Controller Class:

```
class AuthenticateController {
    constructor(router, passport) {
        this.router = router;
        this.registerRoutes();
        this.passport = passport;
    }

    registerRoutes() {
        this.router.post('/login/:username/:password', this.login.bind(this));
        //this.router.get('/logout', this.logout.bind(this));
        this.router.get('/content', this.content.bind(this));
    }

    login(req, res) {
        this.passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}),
            res.redirect("/content");
    }

    content(req, res ) {
        console.log(req.user);
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.send("Congratulations! you've successfully logged in.")
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    }
  isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.sendStatus(401);
}
}

module.exports = AuthenticateController;
```

The Controller gets the router and passport fully configured as parameters from my index.js.

//index.js

```
var express = require('express')
    , cors = require('cors')
    , app = express()
    , passport = require('passport')
    , morgan = require('morgan');

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(require('express-session')({secret: 'vidyapathaisalwaysrunning',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());

var apiRouter = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
//
var apiV1 = express.Router();
apiRouter.use('/v1', apiV1);

var authenticateApiV1 = express.Router();
apiV1.use('/auth', authenticateApiV1);

var AuthenticateController = require('./controllers/authenticate');
var ac = new AuthenticateController(authenticateApiV1, passport);   //pass in our fully configured passport

//If I call this /login instead of the /auth/login/ in the Controller Class it works!
//app.post("/login",
//    passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}),
//    function (req, res) {
//        res.redirect("/content");
//    });
```

**What is working and what is not working**

The Authentication in *general* is working. In my posted index.js you see `app.post("/login", ...`. If I call this one the authentication is successfully and if I try to reach the *restricted content* in /auth/content/ `req.user` has a value (the user object) and I can successfully call `req.isAuthenticated()` .

BUT, If I use the authentication from `/auth/login/username/password` the `req.user` is **undefined** when trying to reach the restricted Content. 
I get no error and the response of `/auth/login/username/password/` HTTP Code 301 - 'redirecting to /content.

I have currently no idea what I´m doing wrong here and I´m pretty new to the topic of Node/express/ passport ..

Hope someone has an Idea. If you need something else to help me, just mention it in the comments and I will do my best to provide you everything you need.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I recently tried to read the `req.user` in the login function and even there it is undefined

```
login(req, res) {
        this.passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}),
            console.log(req.user) //undefined
            res.redirect("/content");
    }
```

I guess it could be some async problem and I should use some callback functions, but I don´t know how to apply this in my `login()`

EDIT 2:

Another Issue I´m facing is the integration of the isLoggedIn() request.

If I do this:

```
registerRoutes() {
                this.router.get('/', this.isLoggedIn, this.getUsers.bind(this));
                this.router.get('/:id', this.getSingleUser.bind(this));
            }
```

it results in `401 - Unauthorized`

A `console.log(req.user);` in the `isLoggedIn()` results in undefined.

But if I call the first route without calling `isLoggedIn()` and do `console.log(req.user);` the user object exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct use of callback with passport authentication for local strategy can be as below:

`function(req, res, next){
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
    if(err)
      return logger.log('error', err);
    if(user)
      req.login(user, function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
        return res.json({'success': true}); 
      });
    if(!user)
      return res.json({'error':true, 'message': info.message, 'type': info.type});
  })(req, res, next);

}`

Please note the use of req.login() to explicitly set user in session.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your solution was the only solution where I didn´t run into a timeout and it seems to work! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'm finding strange is that your route declarations are different.

In the `AuthenticateController` the route is declared as:

```
this.router.post('/login/:username/:password', ...
```

While in `index.js`, the route is simply declared as

```
app.post("/login", ...
```

How is your client submitting the login credentials to the server? If it is by form, like [the tutorial](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password), could it be that having `:username` and `:password` declared as route params but being sent by form messes with passport?

Try registering the route exactly like `index.js`

```
this.router.post('/login', ...
```

EDIT:
I've found another dicrepancy. In `AuthenticateController` the `res.redirect("/content");` is not wrapped inside a callback. So it is being executed before `Authenticate` finishes running.

In the `index.js` example, passport is being used as a route middleware:

```
app.post("/login", 
    passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect("/content");
    });
```

While in the `passport.js` it is inside the callback. Consider declaring it in the route:

```
registerRoutes() {
    this.router.post('/login', this.passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}), this.login.bind(this));
    (...)
}

login(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/content");
}
```

O, better yet, why not use [`passport's` option to declare both success and failure redirects](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate), since that seems to be all that you are doing:

```
login(req, res) {
    this.passport.authenticate("local-login", { successRedirect: "/content", failureRedirect: "/login" });
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but It´s not helping. I´m using the Chrome Plugin ARC to send the Request´s. Any other ideas?

Comment: @elsololobo take a look at my edit. I've suggested a few other changes that could help you

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this.login.bind(this)` as a middleware to `this.router.post('/login/:username/:password', this.login.bind(this));` but `login(req, res)` only responds to the request with `res.redirect("/content");` i.e. redirecting to */content*

So like you said, you need to supply a callback that does something with the user that is returned from passports middleware verify callback.

```
app.post("/login",
  passport.authenticate("local-login", { failureRedirect: "/login"}),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user); // log user in console
    res.json({user: req.user}); // send user as json response
});
```

The **custom** callback mentioned by @divsingh is if you want to explicitly have control of setting the session, error messages and redirecting the request. Any other information can be found under http://passportjs.org/docs